# How to configure multiple ibm mq brokers?

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

I've tried to follow this [guide](https://dev.to/adzubla/using-multiple-jms-servers-with-spring-boot-3cbm), but problem occured: I have to use spring boot version 2.7.11 which does not contain com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConnectionFactoryFactory class.
I assume if the class was removed, there should be another solution to configure multiple ibm mq jms brokers?

I need to create bean MQConnectionFactory which would use my MQConfigurationProperties.

Comment: Do you have `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and ` jms.jar`?

Comment: First one yes. and I have javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the tutorial that @Rich mentions take a look at pattern 114 : Custom connection beans
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/eecc42470a821c05e11e0f0fb10477ad01bf6806/Spring-JMS#level-114-sample

ie. https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/eecc42470a821c05e11e0f0fb10477ad01bf6806/Spring-JMS/src/main/java/com/ibm/mq/samples/jms/spring/level114/MQConfiguration114.java

which shows how to create a custom connection factory. Which in turn allows two or more custom factories enabling an application to create connections to multiple MQ host / port / channel combinations.

If you have

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

as a dependency (current version is 3.1.1), then you should have all the classes you need.

```
import com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConnectionFactoryFactory;


    @Bean
    public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        MQConfigurationProperties properties = new MQConfigurationProperties();
        // Properties will be a mix of defaults, and those found in application.properties
        // under ibm.mq
        // Here we can override any of the properties should we need to
        MQConnectionFactoryFactory mqcff = new MQConnectionFactoryFactory(properties,null);
        MQConnectionFactory mqcf = mqcff.createConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.class);
        return mqcf;
    }
```

Comment: Same problem here. The MQConnectionFactoryFactory is from  com.ibm.mq.spring.boot. I dont have that class in that library

Comment: See the updated answer wrt `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter`

Comment: changing the mq-jms-spring-boot-starter version helped, but now my project can not load com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory class. Any thoughts how to fix that?

Comment: never mind. changing the mq-jms-spring-boot-starter version to 2.3.2 (same as in the tutorial in my question) got me what I needed

Comment: If you have `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` as a dependency it's best to not explicitly put a dependency on `com.ibm.mq.allclient` and `javax.jms-api`. There has been a move away from using `javax.jms.*` to `jakarta.jms.*` that you may have hit.

Answer (score 1):

There is an IBM Tutorial [here](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/). This references a GitHub repository for the IBM MQ Spring Boot Starter, which includes the com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConnectionFactoryFactory class.

Comment: Yea, I tried to copy that class in my project, but it is using another class from that repo which I dont have. I could copy whole library, but is there another way create MQConnectionFactory with MQConfigurationProperties in spring boot version 2.7.11